# link images in ajax slide show

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I had ajax slide show and I tried to make images as href to other link I didnot .

```
<web service>

public AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
{
    return new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] { 
     new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("<a href='NewsEvents.aspx'>images/aboutus_Iso_2.png</a>", "QUALITY ASSURANCE CERTIFICATE ISO", "EL- ARABY group recorded today by Office Equipment"),

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add  on image control which will display images in slid